# sqlalchemy query related tables: to join or not to join (and then to loop)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Objective:

1. Retrieve a list of query results from one table (call it "groups").
2. Retrieve lists of results from a related table (call it "items"). One results list for each of the results from step 1.
3. Combine the "items" lists from step 2 with the corresponding "groups" result from step 1 in a tuple that contains both the "group" data and a list of all the related "items" data.

Question:

Is it more efficient to combine steps 1 and 2 above with a join query and then loop through to sift and aggregate the results by group? Or is it more efficient to query the results for step 1, then loop to query the results for step 2 and and aggregate the results?

Examples of each approach follow, hoping there is some other much better way...

Single query with loop approach (with join):

```
# query all "groups" in "category1" and all related "items"
results = session.query(Group.id, Group.name, Item.id, Item.name).\
    outerjoin(Item, Group.items).\
    filter(Group.category == 'category1').\
    order_by(Group.id).\
    all()

groups = list()
group_ids = set(results[0][0])
current_group = results[0][:2]
current_group_items = list()

for result in results:
    # for each result, combine "group" with all related "items"
    if result[0] in group_ids:
        current_group_items.append(result[2:])
    else:
        groups.append(current_group + (current_group_items,))
        group_ids.add(result[0])
        current_group = result[:2]
        current_group_items = [result[2:]]
```

Multiple query with loop approach (no join):

```
# query all "groups" in "category1"
groups = session.query(Group.id, Group.name).\
    filter(Group.category == 'category1').\
    all()

results = []

for group in groups:
    # for each "group", query all related "items"
    items = session.query(Item.id, Item.name).\
        filter(Item.group_id == group[0]).\
        all()
    # append list of related "items" to "group" result
    results.append(group + (items,))
```

Example schema for reference:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


Base = declarative_base()

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
    category = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
    items = relationship('Sub', back_populates='group', cascade='all')

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), nullable=False)
    group = relationship('Group', back_populates='items')
```

Comment: Note that your 1st approach seems to incorrectly assume that rows belonging to a single group follow one another in the results. The order is not guaranteed and could change at the whim of the DBMS.

Comment: I edited the 1st approach code example to include an `order_by` which I think should resolve that particular issue, but your answer using `joinedload` is the better way that I was looking for. Although, I had read through [Relationship Loading Techniques](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html), your comment about the default relationship loading strategy finally made it click for me. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the order by resolves that particular nit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also the 3rd option using a join: let SQLAlchemy eager load items and handle the grouping for you, since you've established the relationships between `Group` and `Item` already:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload

groups = session.query(Group).\
    options(joinedload(Group.items)).\
    filter(Group.category == '...').\
    all()
```

You'd then access items of a group using the `Group.items` collection.

Generally speaking a [`joinedload`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading) performs better than the "1+N" queries approach in your second example, because of the latencies involved in performing queries. That's of course a generalization and at times separate queries might even win, but even in that case you could still use the relationships – the default relationship loading strategy is [`'select'`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#relationship-loading-techniques).